# Access variable in main function from other script

Tags: python, python-3.x, program-entry-point

this is probably a silly question but I'm a little bit struggling to make it work :

Let's say I have two files :

**script1.py :**

```
    myValue = 0

def addition():
    global myValue
    myValue += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    addition()
    print(myValue)
```

**script2.py :**

```
def getMyValue():
    from script1 import myValue
    print(myValue)

getMyValue()
```

Output : 0

I want my 2nd script to access the updated value so I can get '1' as output.
How do you think I can do it properly ?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: It looks like `myValue` is only updated unless you actually call the `addition()` function. What is the more general problem you're trying to solve? Because in general mutable global variables are not a good way to pass around data.

Comment: @Iguananaut yes, that's it, i only need to get  `myValue` value updated so the second script can get the updated value (1),. I'm not really familiar with the `if __name__ == '__main__'` but it returns 0. I'm surely missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `myValue` is not updated in script2.py as you don't call the `addition()` function by importing script1. That is due to the condition
`if __name__ == '__main__'` which ensures that every following logic is only executed if you run the script itself. If you import script1 into another script the condition `if __name__ == '__main__'` becomes `False` and none of the below code will run.
You could either just call `addition()` directly in script1, which would not be a very clean solution -
**script1:**

```
myValue = 0

def addition():
    global myValue
    myValue += 1

addition()
```

or reconsider if `addition()` actually needs to operate on a global variable. Be aware that globals in python are just global within a module and not across several modules, so importing both the variable and the function into script 2 would not allow you to call `addition()` in script2 with the expected effects. However, i would suggest making it accept a parameter like this - **script1**:

```
myValue = 0

def addition(a_value):
    a_value += 1
    return a_value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myValue = addition(myValue)
    print(myValue)
```

and then call the addition function in script2, for example as follows - **script2**:

```
from script1 import *

def getMyValue():
    my_new_value = addition(myValue)
    print(my_new_value)

getMyValue()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just have a question, i the `addition` function is called multiple times, `myValue` will stay at `1`, how do I do if I want this to go up to 2, 3, 10... and retrieve it in my second script ? Thanks !